# Sed - Printing a pattern in a line matched more than once

Tags: sed

Input-

> X's Score 1725 and Y's Score 6248 in the match number 576

I want sed to ouput-

> 1725
>
> 6248

My code-

```
sed 's/Score[[:space:]]\([0-9]+\)/\1/g'
```

The above code outputs -

> 1725 and Y's 6248 in the match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `GNU sed` because `\b` that matches a word boundary is an extension.

```
echo "X's Score 1725 and Y's Score 6248 in the match number 576" | sed -e '
    ## Surround searched numbers (preceded by "Score") with newline characters.
    s/\bScore \([0-9]\+\)\b/\n\1\n/g;
    ## Delete all numbers not preceded by a newline character.
    s/\([^\n0-9]\)[0-9]\+/\1/g;
    ## Remove all other characters but numbers and newlines.
    s/[^0-9\n]\+//g;
    ## Remove extra newlines.
    s/\n\([0-9]\)/\1/g; 
    s/\n$//
' infile
```

It yields:

```
1725
6248
```

Comment: I not just want any number but number followed by keyword Score and even I am not sure of how many patterns can be there in the input

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following sed commands

```
#!/bin/sed f
s/Score\s*/\
/g
s/\n\([0-9]\+\)[^\n]*/\
\1/g
s/^[^\n]*\n//
```

The first command replaces all "Score"s with newlines, so now all numbers are at the beginning of a line. To insert a newline character, we must write a backslash followed by an actual line break. That's why the command spawns two lines.

The second command will remove everything after the numbers that are on the beginning of a line. It will match a newline character followed by a number (this is how we now that this number was prefixed by a "Score" string). The number will be captured into variable `\1`. Then it will skip all characters up to the newline character. When writing the replacement, we must restore the newline character and the number that was captured into `\1`.

Because the first line contains text before the first "Score", we must remove it. That's what the last command does, it matches all characters up to the first newline, starting from the beginning of the contents of the pattern space (ie. our working buffer).

In a single command:

```
sed -e 's/Score\s*/\
/g;s/\n\([0-9]\+\)[^\n]*/\
\1/g;s/^[^\n]*\n//'
```

Hope this helps =)

Comment: I not just want any number but number followed by keyword Score and even I am not sure of how many patterns can be there in the input

Answer (score 0):

You could AND two egreps:

```
<infile egrep -o 'Score [0-9]+' | egrep -o '[0-9]+$'
```